# How can one export a datatype record in haskell without exporting its fields?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I saw the somewhat older question at [Avoiding namespace pollution in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260507/avoiding-namespace-pollution-in-haskell) and am looking for a modern solution using lenses.

I think the approach would come in a few steps:

1. Rewrite fields to be lens friendly: `field` -> `_field`.
2. Use lenses.
3. Avoid exporting (or if on the user's side, importing) the `_field`s.

I'm mostly concerned with point 3 in this question, as I think I can figure out the rest based on existing resources. But, maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: Why not simply not name the fields, and write seperate field-fetching functions?

Comment: Why does point 3 concern you, exactly?

Comment: name clashes become annoying: I can imagine having e.g. a `time` field in many different record types, and they even mean the same thing. I guess not naming the fields might be an option.

Comment: @bbarker The answers on the question you linked discuss what to do about that... (Use a typeclass, a prefix, or imports with qualified+as.) I'm very, very tempted to just mark this as a duplicate of that one. Lenses don't really change the answer significantly.

Comment: I think the thing that is still tripping me up: say I have a datatype named `Record` with `Record{id:: Int}` - is there a way to be able to refer directly to an unprefixed `Record` and then also do something like `RCD.id` where `RCD` is the qualified import to use the `id` field (or to just not have them imported at all, as my original question states, which is the main difference from the prior question, I suppose).

Comment: In addition to a qualified import, you can make an unqualified import of only the `Record` type. `import qualified ThePackage AS RCD; import ThePackage (Record)`

Comment: @4castle - great, that does work. Somehow I was still thinking this was like JVM-land where the names might class on import, but in Haskell (since things are always lazy?) I suppose they only class on use (i.e. if there is ambiguity during a call).